# How do I extend an object with its own typeguard in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to add a type guard as the object method. I have an array of objects that contain a lot of data that should be handled the same way. But they also contain important differences to check and guard with typescript.

```
interface RangeElement extends Element {
  value: number;
}

interface SelectElement extends Element {
  value: string[];
}
```

I want to avoid the necessity to import the type guard into each component that needs to check the type of the element. So, I extended my Element like

```
interface GuardedElement extends Element {
  isRangeElement(): boolean;
}

class Element {
  ...
  public isRangeElement = () => myTypeGuardToCkeck()
}
```

I would like to have my code in SubComponents look like this

```
if (element.isRangeElement()) {
  doSomething();
}
```

But typescript doesn't accept that evaluation. I guess it is because isRangeElement returns a boolean instead of something like.
isReangeElement(): 'you can be sure the extended element is a range element.

How can I achieve this check?

Comment: Probably you're looking for the return type `this is RangeElement` instead of `boolean`, but please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WoDVLw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thank you, that already did the trick. I just didn't find the according docs in Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is possible via type guards:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-based-type-guards

Say for example:

```js
public isRangeElement: this is RangeElement { return this.range; }
```

The `this.range` comes from the concrete class and TypeScript runs the checks at compile time.

Comment: Why would the body be `this.range`?  It needs to return a `boolean`-assignable value.  I mean, I guess this is all pseudocode, but it's nice when questions and answers don't have unrelated problems to distract from the issues involved

Comment: @jcalz If you take a look at the sample code found in the link it is returning a `boolean` assignable value at runtime.

Comment: But in your actual answer the body of the function does not `return` anything, so it's not possible for it to compile as written without error, right?

Comment: Ah, excellent point. My mistake, fixed.